# Как смоделировать платные возможности?

Tags: алгоритм, архитектура, биллинг, тарификация

В веб-сервисе есть регулируемые ресурсы. Их наличие/отсутствие/величина – то, за что берут оплату. Можно купить отдельную фишку, или проподнять отдельный параметр на какое-то время. Можно купить «тарифный план», включающий набор продвинутых параметров и действующий месяц.

**Вопрос: как лучше описать / управлять этими ресурсами в рамках приложения?** Вероятно, для разработчиков игр, хостинга или операторов мобильной связи тема избитая и давно решённая.

Интересно услышать мнение реализовавших что-то подобное в своих проектах.

Сложности возникли при учёте коллизий. Напр., купил тариф `T.A`, в котором параметр `P1` поднимается до 100. Этот `T.A` действует 1 календарный месяц. Но пользователь взял, и через две недели купил отдельный апгрейд `P1` до 200, сроком на 2 недели.

Для некоторых параметров возможно сложение: т.е. на две недели у пользователя будет `P1 = 100+200 = 300`. Для некоторых сложение невозможно, и нужно последовательно держать `P1 = 200`, а по истечении апгрейда продолжить на уровне тарифа `P1 = 100`. И ещё вопрос, продлить ли это на 2 недели, или отключить, как только пройдёт месяц действия тарифа? (По-честному, надо продлить, пожалуй.)

Система растёт, и будут появляться новые «предметы для торга» и новая бизнес-логика. Как более-ли-менее разумно заранее предусмотреть возможные усложнения маркетинга?

Пока каждый Параметр заносится в БД, вместе с описанием его свойств: добавляется или последователен, и т.п. При покупке пользователь приобретает Товар, который состоит из одного или нескольких Параметров, и имеет срок действия. И купленные Параметры заносятся в таблицу Активаций: сегодня со знаком плюс, и по окончании действия, с минусом. При появлении для одного Пользователя нескольких одинаковых Параметров, их даты корректируются.

Answer (score 2):

Для начала: я ни разу не реализовывал игровую логику в своём коде. Поэтому воспринимайте эти рекомендации не как финальное слово, а как предположение.

---

Итак, я бы сделал следующую логику:

1. У нас есть набор объектов, предоставляющих собой апгрейды (и, возможно, даунгрейды). Объекты сами по себе более-менее пассивные. Например, они могут получив на вход силу удара/скорость заживления ран/процент скидки на товары, вычислить тот же параметр после применения апгрейда. Или получив набор свойств участника, выдать новый набор с применёнными апгрейдами. Но они сами этого не делают, их должен вызвать другой кусок кода для этого. Плюс, возможно, нужны дополнительные параметры наподобие кумулятивности (два апгрейда силы удара на 100% увеличивают в сумме на 100%? 200%? 400%?) и границ применимости (усилить свои магические свойства может только маг).
2. Следующая сущность — покупка. Она представляет собой апгрейд и период его действия. Имея участника и список покупок, можно определить активный на данный момент список апгрейдов.
3. У пользователя есть *базовый* набор свойств (сила удара, шанс найти артефакт и т. п.), которые изменяются со временем (оружие, количество побед, ...). При применении активных на данный момент апгрейдов получается effective (действующий в данный момент) набор свойств. Превращением базового набора в действующий занимается [отдельная часть бизнес-логики](http://ericlippert.com/2015/05/11/wizards-and-warriors-part-five/) — комбинатор апгрейдов. Именно эта часть следит за правилами и пересчитывает действующий набор свойств когда необходимо (например, каждый раз).

Как при этом разрешаются проблемы?

Тариф `T.A` и апгрейд `P1` являются частью активного списка апгрейдов. Если первый из них — апгрейд *на* 50 единиц, а второй — апгрейд *на* 150 единиц, и они кумулируются, получится суммарный апгрейд *на* 200 единиц. Если первый из них — апгрейд *до* 100 единиц, второй — апгрейд *до* 200 единиц, то наверное имеет смысл сделать их *некумулятивными*, и будет взят, согласно бизнес-логике, наилучший из вариантов. Или наихудший.

Если не все апгрейды складываются друг с другом, то выбор снова-таки кодируется бизнес-логикой комбинатора апгрейдов. Например, можно попробовать все комбинации (первый комбинируется со вторым — берём это как один возможный вариант и т. п., второй с третьим, но тогда не с первым — другой вариант), и выбрать среди их наилучшую.

Таким образом вы можете закодировать как угодно сложную бизнес-логику.

Добавление нового типа апгрейдов сводится к

- созданию нового класса, описывающего апгрейд, и
- добавлению, если нужно, кастомной бизнес-логики в комбинатор апгрейдов.

Держать в отдельной таблице действующий набор свойств, судя по всему, не нужно, т. к. это мешает другой логике программы. Например, если у пользователя было 50 единиц здоровья, он купил апгрейд, умножающий здоровье на 2, и затем получил ранение, которое отняло у него 10 единиц базового здоровья, его действующий показатель здоровья станет равным 80, а по истечению срока апгрейда — 40. Эта логика легко кодируется, если у вас базовые и действующие параметры разделены, и довольно сложно, если всё лежит вперемешку.

Comment: "Превращением базового набора в действующий" -- практически event sourcing :).

Comment: @andreycha: Угу, мы как бы проигрываем историю покупок каждый раз.